# image classification with TFLITE model & flutter

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I just made android flutter app that uses tensorflow-lite for image classification
it should recognize images for specific kind of diseases everything is working good .
I got the result back with the correct output
but when I insert image of something else ( car ) for example .. The result shows one of the diseases
I searched everywhere to figure it out but I couldn't find any solution
how to not show the results of another images ?

is there any solutions ?

Comment: Did you find a solution meanwhile? Im having exact the same problem. I trained my model with cats and dogs and if i put a different image (for example a human) i also have a nearly 100% output of  cat or dog. How can we not show the result?

Comment: Hi ! Could you Clarify your question on the image classification ? If it is about about under-fitting you should put more data in folders and try normalizing the those images. Need a sample stand alone code to understand this issue.